# CancellationToken для задачи обертки?

Tags: c#, async-await

Доброго времени суток!!!
Использую в проекте библиотеку для чтения по протоколу Modbus rtu.
Но обнаружил что в нее не передается параметр время ожидания и/или CancellationToken.
Что должно быть обязательно в таких блокирующих на долго поток задачах.
ReadHoldingRegistersAsync(slaveAddress, startAddress, numberOfPoints);

Решил сделать обертку и отменять задачу по истечении времени.

```
 public async Task<ushort[]> ReadHoldingRegistersAsync(byte slaveAddress, ushort startAddress, ushort numberOfPoints, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        return await await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            Task<ushort[]> task = _master.ReadHoldingRegistersAsync(slaveAddress, startAddress, numberOfPoints);

            while (!task.IsCompleted)
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            return await task;
        }, ct);
    }
```

Где вначале создаю горячую задачу и потом пока задача не завершилась проверяю состояние токена отмены.

Вызывающий код:

```
 using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeRespoune))        //время на ожидание ответа
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] sendBuffer = dataProvider.GetDataByte();
                if (sendBuffer == null || !sendBuffer.Any())                                     //READ
                {
                   var takeBuff = await ReadHoldingRegistersAsync(slaveAddress, startAddress, (ushort)(dataProvider.CountGetDataByte / 2), cts.Token);

                } 
                else                                                                             
                _countTryingTakeData = 0;

            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {

                StatusString = string.Format("Время на ожидание ответа вышло");

                if (++_countTryingTakeData > numberTryingTakeData)
                    Connect();
            }            
        }
```

Все это вызывается в цикле опроса, т.е. ждем данные N секунд если ответа нету то по OperationCanceledException выходим из блока чтения, и повторяем заново.

ПРОБЛЕМА:
Смотрю в отладчике и система с токеном отмены работает, но данные в порт отправляются 1 раз. Т.е. статус таска запущен но в порту ничего нету. Прерывается по OperationCanceledException заходит заново формирует новый таск (новый id) заходит в цикл проверки отмены но данных в порту нету. Это что то я не так делаю или библиотека такая?

Comment: `while (!task.IsCompleted)` o_O

Comment: И что? пока задача не завершится, т.е. пока счетчик байт в порту не насчитает нужное кол-во. мы находимся в цикле проверки токена отмены. любая отмена в цикле проверяется.

Comment: Ну, хм, попробуйте оценить, сколько миллионов раз пробегает тело цикла.

Comment: я проверял на тестовом task. замена ReadHoldingRegistersAsync. где делал блокировку потока на время большее или меньшее заданное в токене отмены. И все срабатывает так как надо, если задача завершится быстрее то вернется результат без OperationCanceledException. Если не успеет то вылетит OperationCanceledException.

Comment: Ну и что токен отмены проверять то надо? или вы хотите проверять редко например по тикам таймера. Но это лишняя прилипуха. Тогда ващ вариант отмены асинхронной опреации?

Comment: Извиняюсь нужно отойти от компа буду через 2 часа и продолжим)) большое спасибо Влад за участие!!!

Comment: Окей, у меня есть идеи, напишу пока ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, у вас busy waiting: цикл

```
while (!task.IsCompleted)
{
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

должен потреблять впустую довольно много ресурсов, постоянно переспрашивая состояние Task'а. Есть смысл переписать эту логику более дружественным к процессору способом:

```
async Task WaitCancellation(CancellationToken ct)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    using (ct.Register(() => tcs.SetResult(0)))
        await tcs.Task;
}

public async Task<ushort[]> ReadHoldingRegistersAsync(
    byte slaveAddress, ushort startAddress, ushort numberOfPoints, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var mainTask =
        _master.ReadHoldingRegistersAsync(slaveAddress, startAddress, numberOfPoints);
    var cancellationWaitTask = WaitCancellation(ct);

    var firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(mainTask, cancellationWaitTask);

    if (firstFinishedTask == cancellationWaitTask)
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    return await mainTask;
}
```

Заодно и `Task.Factory.StartNew` не понадобилось.

---

Теперь по делу. Отменить бегущую операцию снаружи сложно, потому что она должна по окончанию подчистить внутренние структуры данных. Вы по сути бросаете бегущий таск на произвол судьбы, и параллельно ему начинаете следующий. Это может оказаться не вполне верной идея, т. к. параллельный таск будет наверняка пользоваться теми же структурами данных, и два таска будут мешать друг другу. (Ну тут лучше, конечно, поинтересоваться у авторов библиотеки.)

В вашем случае, судя по всему, вы пользуетесь библиотекой, которая пишет в порт (serial?), так что вы можете «жёстко» оборвать таск, просто закрыв порт. У `SerialPort` можно вызвать `Dispose`, при этом операция внутри `ReadHoldingRegistersAsync` завершится аварийно с исключением, объект `_master` окажется в плохом состоянии, так что вам придётся пересоздать `_master` снова. Это может быть не таким уж плохим решением (я пользовался им для управления USB-устройством через `SerialPort`).

В этом случае ваш внешний код должен по приходу `OperationCanceledException` (или что там будет выброшено) закрыть текущий `_master` и пересоздать его снова. Или найти несущий `SerialPort`, закрыть его, поймать исключение из его последней операции, и наконец закрыть текущий `_master` и пересоздать его снова.

---

Разумеется, самым чистым и правильным решением было бы наличие поддержки `CancellationToken` в `ReadHoldingRegistersAsync`. Но это может быть и невозможно, например, если целевое устройство не сумеет после обрыва коммуникации посередине передачи информации восстановить её без специальных на то команд.

Comment: Спасибо!! То-есть я запускаю 2-е задачи параллельно и смотрю какая завершится быстрее. А вот можно поподробнее про метод WaitCancellation. Ведь аналогично можно запускать Tack.Delay(time)?

Comment: И ошибка у меня была что я использовал 1 экземпляр _master на все задачи. Т.е.  var master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(_port) я создаю в начале ReadHoldingRegistersAsync. Ну и походу нужно сразу пере инициализировать порт при возникновении OperationCanceledException. Иначе в порт летят больше запросов, т.е. старые таски влияют.

Comment: @Aldmi: Да, так и есть, можно параллельно запустить `Task.Delay`. наверное будет даже проще.

Comment: @Aldmi: Именно так, старые экземпляры `master` лучше убивать.

Comment: Все таки про WaitCancellation можете рассказать? ни разу не встречал)

Comment: @Aldmi: А что про него рассказывать? Создаётся Task, который завершается, когда токен `ct` отменят. Любое событие можно по сути превратить в `Task`.

Comment: @Aldmi: Вы никогда не работали с TaskCompletionSource?

Comment: Нет ни разу)). Хорошо почитаю, похору я много упустил)

Comment: @Aldmi: Смотрите. `TaskCompletionSource` — это такая штука, которая создаёт `Task`, а когда именно этот `Task` закончится, мозно управлять через `SetResult`. Я так и делаю: подписываюсь на `Cancel` у токена, и когда он происходит, вызываю `SetResult`. `await` нужен для того, чтобы уничтожить подписку на `Cancel`.

Comment: понял, колбэк токена завершает задачу, а await чтобы using отработал.

Comment: Спасибо огромное не первый раз помогаете!!!

Comment: @Aldmi: Пожалуйста!